# What is native OS

Tags: operating-system, terminology

I have searched the web but couldn't find any detailed idea about Native OS development I need to know about Native OS development in detail eg. what is a Native OS what kind of feature it gives.. etc etc..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Native OS" is not a product. It is a phrase that describes the operating system that the device comes with, and applications written specifically for that OS (as opposed to Java apps, which are cross-platform).

So for example, "Native OS" of iPhone is iOS; and "Native OS iPhone application" will be written in Objective C. On the other hand, e.g. a JavaScript application running on iPhone is not native, because a Javascript application is running through a browser and not directly on the OS.

Another example: On a Windows machine, the native OS is (obviously) MS Windows. C++ applications using Windows API are native; Flash or TCL/TK would be non-native.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer native OS you should specify what exactly it is, like Windows, Linux... etc. :)